# compile time type at runtime

Tags: java, runtime, compile-time

Is there any way in Java to get the compile time type of a reference at runtime?

Example:

```
private void doSomething(final Object o)
{
   // do somthing
}

final Number n = 1; 
doSomething(n);

final Object o = 1; 
doSomething(o);

final Integer i = 1; 
doSomething(i);
```

1st call --> Number

2nd call --> Object

3rd call --> Integer

Edit: This is a very simplified version of the problem. What i am trying to do is to detect(instead of being told) inside a framework metadata about objects being passed. What could happen is, that the method gets first called with an Integer and then with a Double, both declared as Number.

Comment: `getClass()`? Maybe check out the API.

Comment: @Dave Newton that would return Integer not Number.

Comment: It's at least partially possible; see my answer. Although I'm not sure why you need to know the compile-time type.

Comment: @Dave Newton because i can use that information to generate meta data without passing that information explicitly to the framework.

Comment: This question and your responses to the answers leads me to believe you should redesign whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: @Paul i have already explained what i am trying to do. Wheater or not any of this will ever make it into a production system is a different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I see is to use overloading. But you would need to specify a overlading method for each class of the inheritance relation to exclude sub classes.

```
private void doSomething(final Object o)
{
   // do something
}

private void doSomething(final Number n)
{
   // do something
}

private void doSomething(final Integer i)
{
   // do something
}

final Number n = 1;
doSomething(n); // doSomething(final Number) is called.
```

Comment: I was afraid i had to use overloading, but i may be able to limit the types and then have the code generated.

Comment: This may not be that bad after all. I could create Interfaces for supported Datatypes and then use a Proxy/Handler to put the meta data handling code into it. Clients could even create their own interfaces and the generic InvocationHandler would still work.

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, you can't.

You already know the compile-time of the function argument (`Object`) and you can find out the run-time type of the object that's passed in (by using `getClass()`). However, there's no way to get the information you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use object.getClass()

```
private static void doSomething(final Object o) {
    System.out.println(o.getClass().getSuperclass());
}
```

---

```
private static <T extends Number> void doSomething(final T o) {
    System.out.println(o.getClass());
}


final Integer n = 2;
doSomething(n);

final Double n = 2D;
doSomething(n);
```

Comment: That returns Integer not Number.

Comment: @Stefan, see my answer - you can't have an instance of `Number` because `Number` is an abstract class.

Comment: @Stefan if you put getSuperclass() will get Number, class that inherits Integer.

Comment: @Jhonathan But i dont know its the direct super class. If n was declared as Object it wouldnt work.

Comment: @Jhonathan At least edit your whole answer, not just the source.

Comment: @Stefan Unless it's a field and you get the declared field, as people are trying to tell you, this won't work. But *anything* could be declared an object; of what value is that information to your framework? You can't make any decisions based on it because anything could be an object. Or inspect the byte code, perhaps.

Comment: @Dave Newton As you can see with H-Man2's answer there is actually a way to get the compile time type. Is it going to be alot of boilerplate code? Yes. Is it going to be limited? Yes. I want to see how much information i can detect before i need to start with annotations etc.

Comment: @Stefan That is evaluated at run-time, because you can cast it, and it will take the cast type.

Comment: @Dave Newton what is evaluated at runtime? Method dispatch is compile time.

Comment: @Stefan So... you're claiming Java doesn't have run-time polymorphism?

Comment: @Dave Newton There is no polymorphism here. And which method doSomething is called is decided at compile time. See also http://ideone.com/3mhAB. The compiler even gives a warning for the code there because it knows one of the methods is never called.

Comment: @Stefan But there *could* be, at run time. And my earlier question still stands: if they declare an integer as an Object, or cast it, what will you do? How is knowing it was declared an object going to help you do something with an integer? Or if they have a List<Object> filled with integers, strings, etc and expect your framework to do something useful with it instead of assuming everything is an object?

Comment: @Dave Newton Its a tricky question. We have a huge database here, that i am trying to map out. That is how these tables relate to the Domain Objects. Im trying (mostly for fun in my spare time) to build a program that learns from how these tables are being used by other systems.

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'instanceof'

```
public class Test {
  private static void doSomething(final Object o){
    if(o instanceof Number){
      System.out.println("it's a number!");
    }
    System.out.println("canonical class : "+o.getClass().getCanonicalName());
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Number n = new Integer(10);
    doSomething(n);
  }
}
```

prints out

```
it's a number!
canonical class : java.lang.Integer
```

Another option is to recursively check superclasses

```
public class Test {
  private static Class<?> doSomething(final Object o){
    // assuming o is not null
    Class<?> klass = getSuperClass(o.getClass());
    return klass;
  }

  private static Class<?> getSuperClass(Class<?> klass){
    // if super class is object or null break recursion
    if(klass.getSuperclass() == null || klass.getSuperclass().equals(Object.class)){
      return klass;
    }
    // keep looking higher up 
    return getSuperClass(klass.getSuperclass());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Number n = new Integer(10);
    System.out.println("n  is a "+doSomething(n).getCanonicalName());
    Object o = new Integer(10);
    System.out.println("o  is a "+doSomething(o).getCanonicalName());
    Number d = new Double(10.0d);
    System.out.println("d  is a "+doSomething(d).getCanonicalName());
    String s = "10";
    System.out.println("s  is a "+doSomething(s).getCanonicalName());
    Object so = "10";
    System.out.println("so is a "+doSomething(so).getCanonicalName());
  }
}
```

prints out

```
n  is a java.lang.Number
o  is a java.lang.Number
d  is a java.lang.Number
s  is a java.lang.String
so is a java.lang.String
```

Comment: See edit. I dont know what objects are being passed. Im trying to 'detect' the compile time type.

Comment: In that case I would recommend method overloading and see which method is actually called.

Comment: I am going to try the overloading.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  `Integer` is the correct answer, because `Number` is an abstract class and you can't have an instance of an abstract class, and you relied on autoboxing to convert the primitive `int`.

Comment: It doesnt matter if its abstract. Im trying to get the compile time type, which is indeed Number. See edit.

Comment: You can't have an instance, but you can have a reference; that's what is-a is all about.

Comment: @DaveNewton, an instance is a reference. In Java, passing the instance to another method is just passing the reference (vice passing by value).

Comment: @Paul OP is trying to determine if something is declared as a `Number`. An `Integer` is-a `Number`. You cannot instantiate a `Number`. You *can* declare a reference *as* a `Number` even though you cannot instantiate one directly. An instance is an instance, and may be referred to by types that cannot be directly instantiated. Is-a. You *can* have an instance of `Number`, as-an `Integer`. My point was to differentiate between things-that-are-directly-instantiable, and things-that-may-used-as-reference-types.