# Confusion with subclasses and superclasses

Tags: java, inheritance

```
Master test = new Inner();
System.out.println(test.getClass());
```

In the above example the Inner class extends the Master class, but what I'm confused about is that test.getClass() returns Inner, but isn't test really of the type Master? Other than the constructor no methods/properties can be used from the Inner class, only what's in the Master class. Furthermore the constructor for Inner actually sets properties exclusive to Inner, but somehow these properties don't exist in test even though it uses the constructor -- which doesn't seem like it should work.

For example if define the classes as:

```
public class Master {
    public int number = 0;
    public Master() {
        number = 9;
    }
}

public class Inner extends Master {
    public int innerNumber = 0;
    public Inner() {
        number = 1;
        innerNumber = 2;
    }
}
```

test will use Inner's constructor which sets innerNumber, but test.innerNumber doesn't even exist because innerNumber isn't apart of the Master type. Also, test.getClass() says it's of the Inner type, not Master.

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html

Comment: getClass returns the runtime class of the object: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Object.getClass()` returns the class object of the *dynamic* type of the object, not the static type (the type of the variable or attribute you declared it).

Hence `new Inner().getClass()` returns `Inner.class`, `new Master().getClass()` returns `Master.class` no matter what the type of the variable is that holds the reference.

Comment: How would you go about retrieving the static type of the variable then?

And in the constructor for Inner where innerNumber is assigned a value, is the value never saved because it isn't in the Master class or is innerNumber just inaccessible?

Comment: @Cains You can't and probably you don't need it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8593498/compile-time-type-at-runtime. You can access to `innerNumber` by casting: `((Inner)test).innerNumber`.

Comment: @Cains If the variable is an attribute of a class, you can get the declared type by using reflection. For local variables you don't have the language tools to do that.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1:**

```
Master test = new Inner();
```

The above line indicates that get method implementation's from `Inner` class (**ovveriding**).  So Inner classes `getClass()` method calls.

**Question 2:**

```
test.innerNumber
```

Inheritance happens from Parent to Child. `innerNumber` is a property of `Inner`(child). `Master`(Parent) won't get it.